# npm permission errors on folder access to node_modules

Tags: node.js, npm, macos-high-sierra

I've been trying to get npm configured to where I don't need to run npm using sudo however with everything I try every time I run an npm command I get the following error

```
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /Users/<MYUSERNAME>/.npm-global/lib/node_modules
```

This isn't the full error just edited for brevity.

Here's what I've tried so far:
Installed NVM 
uninstalled then reinstalled node

Tried changing the permissions on the hidden folder

```
chmod 755 /Users/<MYUSERNAME>/.npm-global/lib/node_modules
```

Followed the instructions from npm on how to change the global path
https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions#option-2-change-npms-default-directory-to-another-directory

And finally tried to change ownership of the directory using `CHOWN` and still nothing. Any advice on what I am doing wrong. I've been pouring through Git issues reading what people are doing and still no luck.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2):

For those interested it looks like executing

sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.npm*

from command line/terminal resolved the issue. I think previously I had a syntax error in what I tried. I had to run this from command line then shutdown and restart terminal. Once I restarted terminal I was able to install packages without using sudo and no errors.

I credit this stack link to addressing this issue: 
[npm throws error without sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16151018/npm-throws-error-without-sudo)

**Note**: for clarification for those that don't know (whoami) returns the username of who you are currently logged into your osx/terminal. This does not apply to windows or powershell

If anyone has any other approaches let me know

Comment: This fixed some of my errors, but I still had some relating to the .nvm directory. I ran this as well: `sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.nvm*` and everything works perfectly.